# How to use half angle trigonometric substitution on x/cos(x)

Tags: integration, substitution, trigonometric-integrals

I have this integral that I want to solve for homework: $\int \frac{x}{\cos\left(x\right)}\mathrm{d}x$.

After some research, I found out that I can use a half-angle substitution to solve similar questions. I know what to substitute for $\mathrm{d}x$ and for $\sec(x)$ but I don't know what to substitute for the $x$ remaining.

Comment: Have you tried a by parts integration.

Comment: I did but it becomes too complicated however you do it

Comment: [This](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+x%2Fcos%28x%29) is the solution. Are you *sure* that’s the integral you want to evaluate?

Comment: yes im sure that is the integral that I want to evaluate and btw Symbolab gives a much simpler answer but it uses tan substitution that I don't know how to use.

Answer (score 1):

Typing in Symbolab
$$\int \frac{x}{\cos\left(x\right)}\,dx$$ gives as a result
$$-\log \left(\left|1-\tan ^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right|\right)+C$$ which is totally wrong.

Doing the same using https://www.integral-calculator.com/# gives, just as Wolfram Alpha
$$i \left(\text{Li}_2\left(-i e^{i x}\right)-\text{Li}_2\left(i e^{i
   x}\right)\right)+x \left(\log \left(1-i e^{i x}\right)-\log \left(1+i e^{i
   x}\right)\right)$$  as Chase Ryan Taylor already reported in comments.